# Change the Background Color of a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, background-color, uicolor

I have a problem setting the background color of an `UIView`. I'm using the following code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 
                                            green:0.675 
                                             blue:0.929 
                                            alpha:1];
```

This is working fine when I'm setting the background color right at the start of the app, but when I want to update my background color after I launched my app from a notification center widget, it doesn't change the color.

---

EDIT – Some more details:

When the app is launched from the notification center, an AppDelegate method is called, which saves the called URL Scheme as a `NSString and calls another method in which the background color should be updated.

I've verified the method call works fine.

**My problem is that the color isn't updated although the method is called.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed my problem. In AppDelegate.m, in the method where I got the URL with which the App was launched, I initialized a new ViewController instead of using the old one, which caused all my errors. Thank you for you help!

Comment: Don't forget `importing QuartzCore`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are launching the app from notification center, means that the app is coming from background to foreground. In that case you need to handle the uiview background in methods applicationDidEnter background & applicationDidEnterForeground

Comment: It should really be set in `ViewWillAppear`.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't describe my problem well. When the app is launched from the notification center, an AppDelegate method is called, which saves the called URL Scheme as a NSString and calls another method in which the background color should be updated. The method call works fine; I've tested it with NSLogs.

Answer (score 0):

Update your color in `viewWillAppear` of the controller where your view appears. Set a breakpoint to make sure the code is called and the referenced view is not `nil`.

If you just want to "save" the color without displaying it, use `NSUserDefaults`. You can only store primitives, so you could for example do this.

```
// save
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"0,0.675,0.929" forKey@"savedColor"];

// retrieve
NSString *colorString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"savedColor"];
NSArray *c = [colorString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
CGFloat r = [c[0] floatValue];
CGFloat g = [c[1] floatValue];
CGFloat b = [c[2] floatValue];
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1];
```

Or maybe better more explicit and more concise

```
// save
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:
  @{@"red" : @0, @"green" : @0.675, @"blue" : @0.929} forKey:@"savedColor"];

// retrieve
NSDictionary *c = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey@"savedColor"];
UIColor *color = [UIColor 
   colorWithRed:c[@"red"]  green:c[@"green"] blue:c[@"blue"] alpha:1];
```

Now you put it all into convenience methods:

```
-(void)saveColorToUserDefaults:(UIColor*)color withKey:(NSString*)key {
    CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
    [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:
       @{@"red": @(red), @"green" : @(green), @"blue" : @(blue), @"alpha" : @(alpha)}
       forKey: key];
}

-(UIColor*)colorFromUserDefaultsWithKey:(NSString *)key {
   NSDictionary *c = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey@"savedColor"];
   return = [UIColor colorWithRed:c[@"red"]  green:c[@"green"] 
                             blue:c[@"blue"] alpha:c[@"alpha"]];
}
```

Comment: My ViewDidAppear method is only called when the app launches. I know, it's very strange but what could I have done wrong?

Comment: Put the code into your own public method `updateDisplay` and call that from the app delegate upon notification.

Comment: You are not providing enough information to solve the problem. Show "and calls another method in which the background color should be updated".